# Bash script stop on exit in ssh

Tags: bash, debian

I have a fragment in a bash script:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $SSH_HOSTNAME -p $SSH_PORT <<EOM
    set -e
    echo "test"
    exit
EOM

echo "test 2"
```

Statement "test" is displayed but "test 2" is not.
I also tried to use "exit 0" instead of "exit".

The script worked on an older version of debian (2016), but stopped working after the update (2021).
Why the script stopped working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the script finishing, or is it hanging and never returning?

Comment: Script finishing with error code 1

Comment: `exit` and `exit 0` are equivalent.  How do you know that you got error code 1? You don't output the error code anywhere.

Comment: This script is the last step of deploy gitlab. The last thing I got is: "
test
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1"

Comment: Is this fragment alone sufficient to reproduce the error? The problem has to be in the surrounding context or something you've edited out that we can't see. I don't see how this snippet could both print `test` and fail.

Comment: I reduced the whole script to this form, executed manually from the console, I only get "test" and when after the script I use "echo $?" I get "1"

Comment: Try it with `ssh -vvv` for verbose logging, and `ssh -F /dev/null` to rule out any configuration file issues.

Comment: When I remove the "exit" at the end everything works fine

Comment: How are you running the script? Is `set -e` enabled?

Comment: What happens if you make it `exit 0`?

Comment: `exit 0 ` still fails . It is now the only script.

Comment: I tried it with `ssh -vvv` I've got `debug1: Exit status 1`

Comment: Investigate the machine being SSHed to. There's something fishy there. Check out its SSH config, the remote `.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`, etc.

Comment: If you add `echo "$SHELLOPTS"` before you call ssh, what does it report?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is only a fragment, do you have `set -e` enabled before the fragment in the script? If so, then I assume ssh is returning a non-zero exit code and due to `set -e` being enabled the script exits before reaching `echo "test 2"`

Answer (score 0):

I tested that and, indeed, sending the command with heredoc and this combination of `set -e` and `exit` returns a 1 and not a 0, as tested.
But I think that, somewhere, another `set -e` is set in the context where `echo "test2"` is executed.
We have some solutions that would work:

1. Remove the `exit` because it's not needed, you're sending commands to a target ssh host and the termination of session it's automatic when the heredocs finish.
2. If the script is not so long, switch to inline commands `ssh target "set -e ; echo \"test\"; exit"` works just fine(somehow), but you have to take care of string escaping.